# ¿Cómo resolver el error Invalid Syntax en este código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

*Enunciado*: Programa que solicite varios nombres al usuario y el resultado nos 
     de una lista ordenada de los nombres, nos diga cuál de los nombres tecleados 
     tiene una longitud mayor y lo escriba en mayúsculas.

Me da *invalid syntax* y no se por qué.

El código:

```
#definimos una lista vacia para los nombres
nombres=[]
#definimos otra lista vacia para las longitudes
longitudes=[]
#disponemos un ciclo de 5 vueltas
for x in range(5):
    valor=int(input("Ingrese 5 nombres:"))
    nombres.append(valor)
    longitudes.append(len(nombres[x])

#dispones un ciclo en el cual se comparan las longitudes de los nombres dados 
#para sacar el que tenga mayor longitud
for k in range (5)
    for x in range (2)
            if len (nombres[x])>len(nombres[x+1])
                aux=nombres[x]
                nombres[x]=nombres[x+1]
                nombres[x+1]=aux

print("lista de nombres ordenados:")
print(nombres)

posmayor=0
mayor=longitudes[0]
for x in range(1,5):
    if longitudes[x]>mayor:
        mayor=longitudes[x]
        posmayor=x

posmayor=posmayor.upper()
print(posmayor)

print("El nombre con mayor longitud es...")
print(posmayor)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en que linea te da eso?

Comment: Tienes múltiples problemas, 1) la identación inconsistente del código pareciera ser uno 2) tienes  `for` e `if` que le faltan los dos puntos finales. 3) hay algunos espacios entre el nombre de una función y los parentesis 4) Falta cerrar parentesis en alguna función.

Answer (score 2):

¡Buenas! como dice @gbianchi te recomiendo todas y cada una de las cosas que menciona.

EDITO:
He encontrado varios errores. Te los voy comentando uno a uno y te pongo el código funcionando mas abajo.

- El primer error, del cual no voy a poner código son errores de sintaxis. Faltaban paréntesis y varios dobles puntos durante todo el código, y es algo con lo que debes tener sumo cuidado. Si falta un paréntesis, un punto doble, o una identacion esta mal hecha, tu programa no funcionara. Te recomiendo que lo revises con detenimiento hasta que mejores tus skills en Python.
- El segundo error ha sido un fallo de conversión de tipos. Pongo las secciones de código:

  - Cuando intentas transformar en un entero el input de usuario: Cuando introduzco: "Ruben" y lo tratas de transoformar a entero falla, porque no es un numero.

**MAL**

```py
    for x in range(5):
        valor=int(input("Ingrese 5 nombres:"))
        nombres.append(valor)
        longitudes.append(len(nombres[x])
```

**BIEN**

```py
for x in range(5):
    valor=input("Ingrese 5 nombres:")   
    nombres.append(valor)
    longitudes.append(len(nombres[x]))
```

- Supongo que estarías probando cosas, pero estas dos lineas habría que suprimirlas directamente. ya que no son necesarias.

```py
posmayor=posmayor.upper()
print(posmayor)
```

Si quieras poner el nombre en mayúsculas deberías hacerlo así:

```py
nombres[posmayor].upper()
```

- En las dos ultimas lineas también hay una corrección: Con esas lineas imprimirías la posición en la que se encuentra el nombre mas largo, teniendo la posición debes llamarla desde la lista.

**MAL**

```py
print("El nombre con mayor longitud es...")
print(posmayor)
```

**BIEN**

```py
print("El nombre con mayor longitud es...")
print(nombres[posmayor])
```

Como consejo adicional te recomiendo leer el [PEP 8: Guía de estilo de Python.](http://recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf)

Y aquí dejo el código funcionando, como te prometí.

```py
#definimos una lista vacia para los nombres
nombres=[]
#definimos otra lista vacia para las longitudes
longitudes=[]
#disponemos un ciclo de 5 vueltas
for x in range(5):
    valor=input("Ingrese 5 nombres:")
    nombres.append(valor)
    longitudes.append(len(nombres[x]))

#dispones un ciclo en el cual se comparan las longitudes de los nombres dados 
#para sacar el que tenga mayor longitud
for k in range(5):
    for x in range(2):
            if len (nombres[x])>len(nombres[x+1]): 
                aux=nombres[x]
                nombres[x]=nombres[x+1]
                nombres[x+1]=aux

print("lista de nombres ordenados:")
print(nombres)

posmayor=0
mayor=longitudes[0]
for x in range(1,5):
    if longitudes[x]>mayor:
        mayor=longitudes[x]
        posmayor=x

print("El nombre con mayor longitud es...")
print(nombres[posmayor])
```

¡Un Saludo!

Comment: ese error fue al pasar el programa al cuadro de pregunta.pero aún así gracias :-)

Comment: cómo se copia el código de error?

Comment: @user155343 Perfecto, podemos empezar a mirar otras cosas. Cuando ejecutas el programa te debe dar un error que tiene el siguiente formato: 
`File "ruta", line 4 def get_arguments() SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @user155343 Ya dejé el código funcionando en la respuesta. Espero que te sirva.